# How to force refresh in Curses with Ruby

Tags: ruby, curses

I created a main window `win`:

```
win = Curses::Window.new(Curses.lines / 2, Curses.cols, 0, 0)
```

Then I sometimes need to create a message window, that covers the main one. After I close the message window, I refreshed  `win`:

```
win.refresh
```

But unless I change anything in the main window using something like:

```
win.addstr("asd")
```

`refresh` doesn't redraw the window.

Is there a way to force redrawing the window?

Comment: have you tried `#doupdate`? I have no experience with `Curses` just looking through the docs.

Comment: @engineersmnky no, `#doupdate` doesn't redraw the window.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

That's done using **`touchwin`** (or whatever name a Ruby binding may happen to use for the C function).

In [ruby 2.0.0](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html), the *standard* curses binding for Ruby lacked `touchwin` and `touchline`.  Oddly enough, it included bindings for several of the ncurses extensions (`resizeterm`, the mouse interface, default-colors), but lacks many of the standard features (see [X/Open Curses](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/cursesix.html) for reference).

In 2.4.1, curses is not a standard Ruby module, but the [site for the module](https://github.com/ruby/curses) does have `touchwin`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `Curses::Window#touch` which marks window as changed and to be redrawn by next `refresh`. There is also method `Curses::Window#redraw` which simply redraw the window.

Additional problem is `getch` method, which in my program is little bit unpredictable if I use `Curses.getch` - sometimes it causes that the window wont refresh, sometimes it causes whole screen to disappear... Using `getch` on window object solves the problem e.g. `win.getch`